# `InvocationTargetException` while calling Class.forname

Tags: android, reflection, invocationtargetexception

I am using the following code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                .invoke(myWebView, (Object[]) null);

    } catch (Exception cnfe) {
        cnfe.getCause();
        Logger.appendErrorLog(cnfe.getMessage(), TAG);
    }
```

I am getting `InvocationTargetException` while executing the above code. What is the problem?

Comment: Post your stacktrace - hard to help without it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the dependencies you are using in `pom.xml`. There might be some dependencies conflicting with one another. Make sure it is not caused becaues of any dependencies.